# AngularJS array of objects not displayed but retrieved

Tags: angularjs, json

Cannot display JSON array of objects retrieved from server though it's retrieved OK. It looks like displaying of HTML is done before AngularJS controller is initialized. How can I display data retrieved from server?
Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
    var carApp = angular.module('carsApp', ['ngResource', 'carsApp.services', 'carsApp.controllers']);
```

**carcontroller.js**

```
    angular.module('carsApp.controllers', ['ngResource']);

    carApp.controller('CarController', function($scope, CarService) {
        $scope.items = [
                        {"id":1,"model":"S600","manufacturer":"Mercedes","price":1000.52},
                        {"id":2,"model":"S80","manufacturer":"Volvo","price":500.27}
                       ];
        console.log("Static $scope.items = " + JSON.stringify($scope.items));
        $scope.cars = CarService.getCars();
        console.log("Non-static $scope.cars = " + JSON.stringify($scope.cars));
    });
```

**carservice.js**

```
    angular.module('carsApp.services', ['ngResource']).factory('CarService', function ($http) {
        return {
            getCars: function() {
                    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/cars/' })
                        .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                            console.log('Data in service');
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, header) {
                            console.log('error');
                        });
            }
        }
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Cars View</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_resources/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_resources/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_resources/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/controllers/carcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/services/carservice.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bower_resources/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="carsApp">
        <div ng-controller="CarController">
            <h4>Table content</h4>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in cars[0]">{{key}}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
                    <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in car">{{val}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <h4>Cars list content</h4>
            <ul ng-repeat="car in cars">
                <li>{{car.manufacturer}}</li>
            </ul>
            <h4>Items list content</h4>
            <ul ng-repeat="something in items">
                <li>{{something.manufacturer}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Your `getCars()` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: To be more specific, you should return a promise (or pass and call a callback, which does not actually require returning anything) to handle the async call

Comment: Thanks aw04, your information about promise (which I needed to google for) was valuable to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to modify **carcontroller.js** and **carservice.js** in the following way:

**carcontroller.js**

```
angular.module('carsApp.controllers', ['ngResource']);

carApp.controller('CarController', function($scope, CarService) {
    CarService.getCars()
            .then(
                function(response) { 
                    $scope.cars = response.data;
                    console.log("$scope.cars inside CarService call = " + JSON.stringify($scope.cars));
                },
                function(error) { 
                    $scope.hasErrors = true;
                }
            );
});
```

**carservice.js**

```
angular.module('carsApp.services', ['ngResource']).factory('CarService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getCars : function(carId) {
            var promise;
            promise = $http({ method : 'GET', url : '/cars/', isArray : true })
                    .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                        console.log('Data in service');
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, header) {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
            return promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Now it's all working

Answer (score 0):

```
Use promise chaining.
```

Please do this changes.

**carservice.js**

```
getCars: function() {

                    var objDefer = $q.defer();
                    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/cars/' })
                        .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                            objDefer.resolve(data);
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, header) {
                            console.log('error');
                        });
            }
```

**carcontroller.js**

```
CarService.getCars().then(function(){

    console.log("Non-static $scope.cars = " + JSON.stringify($scope.cars));
},
function(){
 // error
});
```